# Allow google app engine app to access google drive by default

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am trying to save some reports (in csv) on google drive from google app engine. It works fine if I hit the URL directly (after it bounced to google for authorization and click thru the screen to allow the app to access google drive)

But what if I initialize the request from cronjob in google app engine. Is there a way to let the app by passes the click thru? (or have a forever valid token?)

**Note:** same google account for the app and drive

Answer (score 0):

For your app to access a user's data using a cron job, you will first need to get a set of OAuth 2.0 access and refresh token from the user: this should have been already implemented by you through the "click thru".

Once you get those credentials, you just have to store them in the datastore and retrieve them in the cron job in order to perform your tasks.

[Retrieve and Use OAuth 2.0 Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials) shows an example of how to build an authorization flow and how to store/retrieve OAuth 2.0 credentials. Your cron job will simply need to retrieve those stored credentials and use them as usual.